# Implicit interface conversion in golang

Tags: go, interface, type-conversion

Here is an example of the idea I want to demonstrate.

```
package main
import "fmt"

// interface declaration
//

type A interface {
    AAA() string
}

type B interface{
    Get() A
}

// implementation
//

type CA struct {}

// implementation of A.AAA
func (ca *CA) AAA() string {
    return "it's CA"
}

type C struct {}

// implementation of B.Get, except for returning a 'struct' instead of an 'interface'
func (c *C) Get() *CA {
    return &CA{}
}

func main() {
    var c interface{} = &C{}
    d := c.(B)
    fmt.Println(d.Get().AAA())
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

In this example

- interface `B` has a method `Get` to return an interface `A`
- struct `C` has a member function `Get` to return a pointer to struct `CA`, which implements interface `A`

The result is Go can't deduce interface `B` from struct `C`, even their `Get` method is only different in returning type, which is convertible.

The reason I raise this question is when **interface A, B** and **struct C, CA** are in different packages, I can only:

- refine the Get method of `C` to **func Get() A**, which introduce some dependency between packages.
- refine both `Get` method of interface `B` and struct `C` to **func Get() interface{}**

I want to avoid dependency between packages and try not to rely on **interface{}**, can anyone give me some hint? What's the best practice in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current `*C` type **does not** implement the interface `B`, therefore you can't assign a value of `*C` to a variable of type `B` nor can't you "type assert" a value of `B` from something holding a value of type `*C`.

Here's what you can do. Since you're already using a struct literal (`&C{}`), you may declare `c` to be of type `*C` of which you can call its `Get()` method, and you can convert the return value of `C.Get()` to `A` (because the return value does implement `A`):

```
var c *C = &C{}
var a A = c.Get() // This is ok, implicit interface value creation (of type A)
fmt.Println(a.AAA())
// Or without the intermediate "a", you can simply call:
fmt.Println(c.Get().AAA())
```

Output:

```
it's CA
it's CA
```

**Or refactor:**

The problem is that you have an interface (`B`) which you want to implement, which has a method which returns another interface (`A`). To implement this `B` interface, you have to have dependency to the package that defines `A`, you can't avoid this. And you have to declare `C.Get()` to return `A` (instead of a concrete struct type).

You may move `A` to a 3rd package and then the package that defines `C` will only have to depend on this 3rd package, but will not depend on the package that defines `B` (but still will implicitly implement the interface type `B`).